# Pandas: finding start-end values of consecutive indexes in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this (**main_df**):

```
           value               created_at
0   18.930542  2019-03-04 02:43:08 UTC
1   18.895210  2019-03-04 02:44:09 UTC
2    0.000000  2019-03-04 02:45:09 UTC
3    0.000000  2019-03-04 02:46:10 UTC
4    0.000000  2019-03-04 02:47:11 UTC
5    0.000000  2019-03-04 02:48:12 UTC
6    0.000000  2019-03-04 02:49:13 UTC
7   18.857025  2019-03-04 02:50:14 UTC
8   18.857025  2019-03-04 02:51:14 UTC
9   18.847290  2019-03-04 02:52:15 UTC
10  18.847290  2019-03-04 02:53:17 UTC
11   0.000000  2019-03-04 02:54:17 UTC
12   0.000000  2019-03-04 02:55:19 UTC
13   0.000000  2019-03-04 02:56:19 UTC
14  18.837677  2019-03-04 02:57:20 UTC
```

I want to locate segments of repeated zero values inside the column "value". I know how to locate zeros, by just doing this:

```
zeros_df=main_df.loc[main_df['value'] == 0]
```

Which would leave me the following dataframe (**aux_df1**): 
[image: aux_df1]

Now, what I would like to get, and I don't have an idea how, is to keep only the start and beginning of each consecutive index series into a new dataframe named **aux_df2**, and compute the time difference between the beginning and the end of each series of consecutive values in minutes. I intend to do the last part with this (although I'd like to compute the difference just in pairs, between every start-end pair):

```
aux_df2['t_diff'] = ['temp_index'].diff().astype('timedelta64[m]')
```

But the first part I don't know how to do it. What I'm looking for is to make **aux_df2** to look like this:

[image: aux_df2]

Can someone help me please? Thanks in advance.

Edit: in reply to @peer, this is how I'm generating the dataframe. Note that the snapshots above doesn't reflect the timezone change from UTC to EST.

```
import pandas as pd

filepath=r'C:\Users\myfile.csv'
main_df=pd.read_csv(filepath)
main_df['created_at']=main_df['created_at'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
main_df['created_at'] = main_df['created_at'].dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('EST')
```

Comment: could you provide code that generates the example dataset? That will make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Hi @peer, I'm uploading this data from a .csv file, this is just a very small sample of the whole set. All I have done so far is converting timezones from UTC to EST and changing the dtype of the datetime column from object to proper datetime. 

I'll post an edit anyways with it. But in the snapshots I only left relevant information, didn't even changed the proper timezone in there.

Comment: @AquilesPáez what he means, is that we cannot copy your screenshots. Is it possible to `print()` these samples you show in the screenshot and paste the output in your question so we can copy it.

Comment: Man it is going to be a pain trying to get this done without a sample dataframe. I suggest you upload a small csv file on github and share a link to it so we can get data to work with.

Comment: @Erfan sorry, done!

Comment: @SamuelNde yes, my bad. Changed it there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your expected `t_diff` seems not be correct, but here's a solution using [`np.ptp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html) which takes the `maximum - minimum` over a range and [`pandas.Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html)

I used `cumsum` because this way we can find the rows which are `0`

```
df['cumsum'] = df.value.cumsum()

df['t_diff'] = df.groupby('cumsum').created_at.transform(np.ptp)
df.drop('cumsum', axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df)
    Index      value          created_at   t_diff
0       0  18.930542 2019-03-04 02:43:08 00:00:00
1       1  18.895210 2019-03-04 02:44:09 00:05:04
2       2   0.000000 2019-03-04 02:45:09 00:05:04
3       3   0.000000 2019-03-04 02:46:10 00:05:04
4       4   0.000000 2019-03-04 02:47:11 00:05:04
5       5   0.000000 2019-03-04 02:48:12 00:05:04
6       6   0.000000 2019-03-04 02:49:13 00:05:04
7       7  18.857025 2019-03-04 02:50:14 00:00:00
8       8  18.857025 2019-03-04 02:51:14 00:00:00
9       9  18.847290 2019-03-04 02:52:15 00:00:00
10     10  18.847290 2019-03-04 02:53:17 00:03:02
11     11   0.000000 2019-03-04 02:54:17 00:03:02
12     12   0.000000 2019-03-04 02:55:19 00:03:02
13     13   0.000000 2019-03-04 02:56:19 00:03:02
14     14  18.837677 2019-03-04 02:57:20 00:00:00
```

**note** in this case I transform to get the difference next to each row in the group.

Comment: This is perfect and elegant. Truly, I didn't knew this was possible, although Pandas is well renown for being powerful for data manipulation. I was doing something with for/if cycles before I decided to post this question, glad I did. And yeah, I need to gain more depth with Pandas.

Thanks a lot Erfan! :)

Comment: Glad I could help :) and yeah I agree about pandas being elegant and powerful. Happy coding @AquilesPáez

Answer (score 1):

based on the information that you included, I did something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"index":[2,3,4,5,6,11,12,13],"value": [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]})
df["prev_index"] = df["index"].shift(1)
df["next_index"] = df["index"].shift(-1)

df["include"] = df.apply(lambda row: True if np.isnan(row.next_index) or np.isnan(row.prev_index)
         else (True if abs(row["index"]-row.next_index) != 1 
               or abs(row["index"] - row.prev_index) != 1 else False),axis=1)
df[df["include"]][["index","value"]]
```

I created a simple dataframe from the sample you gave, so my idea is just shifting the dataset in order to obtain the previous and next index, based on both columns, I just created a boolean to know if the index is the one I'm looking for. 
Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! Ok, I can use this to do some indexing although is not exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the game here, but I'd like to offer my solution to find the start and end using filtering of the value and the diff of the value:

```
aux_df2 = main_df[
(main_df['value'] == 0) &
(
    (main_df['value'].diff() != 0)
    | main_df['value'].diff().shift(-1) != 0
)]
```

This gives:

```
      value              created_at
2     0.0 2019-03-04 02:45:09+00:00
6     0.0 2019-03-04 02:49:13+00:00
11    0.0 2019-03-04 02:54:17+00:00
13    0.0 2019-03-04 02:56:19+00:00
```

I can't think of an elegant way to get t_diff, though.